# Legend color lines not visible

Tags: plotting, legending

I try to plot several curves on one plot with legends, but the colors assigned to each curve are not showing in the legends.

```
Plot[
  u + (1 - u)*(1/Pi*ArcTan[# (u - 1)] + 1/2) - 
    (u + 1)*(1/Pi*ArcTan[-# (u + 1)] + 1/2), 
  {u, -3, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> 1.3, PlotStyle -> ColorData[91][#], 
  PlotLegends -> ToString[#]] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 10} // Show
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line in the legend does not appear for a single curve

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> "1"]
```

[image]

so the `Map` and `Show` construction will not display the lines either. To get those lines, you can wrap the value of the `PlotLegends` option in a `List`. For the above example, this yields

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> {"1"}]
```

[image]

and for your specific input

```
Plot[u + (1 - u)*(1/Pi*ArcTan[# (u - 1)] + 1/2) - (u + 1)*(1/Pi*ArcTan[-# (u + 1)] + 1/2), 
    {u, -3, 3}, 
    PlotRange -> 1.3, PlotStyle -> ColorData[91][#], PlotLegends -> {ToString[#]}
] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 10} // Show
```

[image]

Another approach that uses only one call to `Plot` could be:

```
val = {1, 2, 3, 10};
Plot[
  Evaluate[(u + (1 - u)*(1/Pi*ArcTan[# (u - 1)] + 1/2) - 
            (u + 1)*(1/Pi*ArcTan[-# (u + 1)] + 1/2)) & /@ val
  ], {u, -3, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> 1.3, PlotStyle -> ColorData[91] /@ val, PlotLegends -> ToString /@ val
]
```

[image]

The vertical spacings of the legends differ from those of the previous plot.

Comment: Perfect !! Thanks a lot for your very clear answer and your additional information for Plot !

Comment: Glad this was helpful :)

Comment: @DoHe to be clear, `PlotLegends` accepts arbitrary expressions, so that when you pass in `"1"` it is displaying the expression you enter which is displayed according to its formatting rules. Wrapping it in a `List` triggers the more extensive legend processing, and it is why you get the line then.